# How to reorder a result when using TOP clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I used this code to select last 5 rows from table:

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM tbl_reg ORDER BY Id DESC
```

But I want to reorder this result ( the last five rows returned ) By Id ASC

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT TOP(5) * FROM tbl_reg ORDER BY Id DESC) t
order by id ASC;
```

Comment: You type faster Gordon

Comment: @Sparky . . . The question had been around for three minutes before I answered ;)